# Drupal 7, сбрасывается сессия на главной

Tags: php, drupal, кэширование

При входе на главную, кука `SESS...`, которая является идентификатором сессии, почему-то сбрасывается, и всегда на одно и то же значение. Не могу найти причину. Поотключал все кэши, результат тот же. Никто не сталкивался с такой проблемой?

При этом я заметил, что главная страница всегда достается из кэша (слишком быстро генерится), не могу понять в каком кэше она хранится.

**UPDATE:**
Заметил, что сброс происходит только если адрес является чистым url типа `http://site.com`, тогда как `http://site.com/index.php` - все нормально.

**UPDATE 2:**
Мне пришлось в конфиге прописать `$base_url = "http://site.com"` т.к. не грузились стили и js, возможно, это важное замечание.

Comment: Может она у вас в браузере закэширована?

Comment: Нет, кэш браузера я добавлял, но дело не в этом (это точно, смотрел в заголовках)

Comment: Посмотрите, какой путь в куке в браузере прописан.

Comment: @Visman, посмотрел `path = /`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался с проблемой. Дело не в Drupal как таковом, а в кэше на прокси-серверах. В комментариях писали про кэш браузера - это дало мне толчок для размышления.

Кэш сохранялся не только в браузере, но еще и на промежуточных серверах, т.к. `Cache-control: public`, т.е. когда шло первое обращение, прокси-сервер запоминал страницу со всеми заголовками, включая переназначение куки (чего я не учел, когда ставил публичность кэша). О том что причина именно в этом, долго не мог догадаться, т.к. если страница возвращается с кэша браузера - это указывается в описании заголовков в хроме, кэш прокси ничего не отличает от серверной обработки, кроме времени.

Не совсем еще понимаю, почему меняется идентификатор сессии на главной (после логина пользователь редиректится не на главную) - но это уже второстепенно.